# Alpha_vanatage module working in cmd prompt of PC (windows) and not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Alpha_vantage package with pip and I am able to import alpha_vantage in python in CMD promt but I am not able to import the same while i am working on Jupyter note book.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k6uB.png)

Comment: Your jupyter notebook is likely to be using a different Python version than your operative system. Try to check the versions being used in both environments. I suggest installing every package you need using conda instead of pip, unless that's your only option.

Comment: I am new to this, Can you please guide how to check it and correct?

Comment: I don't have much understanding of Windows Python configurations but you can run `py -0p` to list the versions installed and respective paths. As a hotfix, try reinstalling the package with conda using `conda install alpha_vantage -c hoishing`. I suggest reading further regarding Python package installations.